# product are not being assigned to categories via magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I am using magmi to upload the product it is working fine product are being uploaded.
Only one problem they are not showing up at front end but they are showing up in admin
when  i try to find the reason I find that products  are  not being assigned to any category when i did that manually they are showing up at fronted.
Any body can help ?

Here is a sample of my CSV

```
sku _store  _attribute_set  _type   _category   _root_category  _product_websites   ada_compliant   backplate_dimension base_dimension  brand   bulb_included   bulb_type   bulb_wattage    canopy_dimension    carton_height   carton_length   carton_width    collection1 cost    country_of_manufacture  country_orgin   created_at  custom_design   custom_design_from  custom_design_to    custom_layout_update    depth   description designer    diameter    dimension   enable_googlecheckout   energy  extension   finish  finish1 gallery gender  gift_message_available  harddrive_speed hardrive    has_options height  height_1    image   image_label in_depth    lamping length  manufacturer1   max_resolution  media_gallery   megapixels  memory  meta_description    meta_keyword    meta_title  minimal_price   model   msrp    msrp_display_actual_price_type  msrp_enabled    name    news_from_date  news_to_date    no_bulbs    options_container   page_layout price   processor   ram_size    required_options    response_time   room    screensize  shade_color shade_dimension shade_material  shape   shirt_size  shoe_size   shoe_type   short_description   small_image small_image_label   special_from_date   special_price   special_to_date status  style   switch  tax_class_id    thumbnail   thumbnail_label updated_at  url_key url_path    visibility  weight  width   qty min_qty use_config_min_qty  is_qty_decimal  backorders  use_config_backorders   min_sale_qty    use_config_min_sale_qty max_sale_qty    use_config_max_sale_qty is_in_stock notify_stock_qty    use_config_notify_stock_qty manage_stock    use_config_manage_stock stock_status_changed_auto   use_config_qty_increments   qty_increments  use_config_enable_qty_inc   enable_qty_increments   is_decimal_divided  _links_related_sku  _links_related_position _links_crosssell_sku    _links_crosssell_position   _links_upsell_sku   _links_upsell_position  _associated_sku _associated_default_qty _associated_position    _tier_price_website _tier_price_customer_group  _tier_price_qty _tier_price_price   _group_price_website    _group_price_customer_group _group_price_price  _media_attribute_id _media_image    _media_lable    _media_position _media_is_disabled
EP777777-81 admin   Default simple  Wall Lights/Wall Sconces        base    No          Maxim Lighting  No  Medium base bulbs   100     29.72   33.66   10.43   Basix   170                                 Contemporary collection with sweeping arms and clean lines. Offered in Ice glass and Satin Nickel finish or Wilshire glass and Oil Rubbed Bronze finish.    Maxim Lighting      31.5 H x 32 W x  L          Dry Locations           Satin Nickel            1                   31.5    /10001CLPC.jpg  Basix 9-Light Chandelier                Maxim Lighting      0           Basix 9-Light Chandelier7777    Ceiling Lights, Chandeliers, lighting, lights, Maxim Lighting   Maxim Lighting Basix 9-Light Chandelier         $510.00             Basix 9-Light Chandelier9999            9           255                                                     Basix 9-Light Chandelier    /10001CLPC.jpg  Basix 9-Light Chandelier                1   Contemporary        2   /10001CLPC.jpg  Basix 9-Light Chandelier                4   26  32  10  0   1   0   0   1   1   1   100 1   1       1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried? Where do you think is the error? Can we have a piece of your CSV?

Comment: I am trying to upload the products via magmi.

Comment: I am trying to upload the products via magmi.here is the link to download the csv.http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1361382059

Comment: I've added the snippet of your CSV to your question.  Please do this next time, instead of providing a download link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
BUT i used the magmi classes into an personal project, not using the magmi interface.
I solved my problem by adding in the product data array the "category_ids"=> "2" . This is the id of the category.
It may not help you, but may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSV, some of your column names are incorrect (including Category)

For example:

```
_store  _attribute_set  _type   _category    _product_websites
```

Should be:

```
store   attribute_set   type    category     websites
```

You can see the required column names at [Magmi: Import New Products](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_new_products)

Also ensure you have the [On the fly category creator/importer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer) plugin enabled in your Magmi configuration, and that your Category column values follow the format outlined in the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Basic_example).

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the field "categories" instead of "category"